# SQL update in one statement instead of two

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to do the following in 1 statement instead of 2. 
I need to set the isActive flag for one id and set all the others to false.
Im using postgres DB.

```
tblNames 
------------------------
id,name,isActive
1,'n1',true
2,'n2',false
3,'n3',false
4,'n4',false

update tblnames
set isActive = true 
where id = 4

update tblnames
set isActive = false 
where id != 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does that work?

```
update tblnames
set isActive = (id = 4)
```

In case it doesn't (I don't know Postgres syntax well enough), this will surely work:

```
update tblnames
set isActive case id when 4 then true else false end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update tblnames
set isActive = (id = 4)
```

Don't know if you can use boolean expressions in updates, but it's worth a shot ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblnames
   SET isActive = CASE 
                    WHEN id = 4 THEN TRUE
                    WHEN id <> 4 THEN FALSE
                  END
 WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```